Intermittent Spring Boot micrometer failed to send metrics to elastic: premature EOF after Elastic 8.16 upgrade
I am using spring boot 3.3.6, looks like it is using micrometer-elastic-registry:1.13.6. I didn't see this errors until I upgrade Elastic from 8.11.4 to 8.16. There were no changes to anything else so I'm not sure why I am getting these intermittent errors. It doesn't happen with very high of frequency but I didn't see them before. I couldn't find anything about incompatibilities between Elastic and Spring versions.
Here is the stack trace from io.micrometer.elastic.ElasticMeterRegistry logger:
ava.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:55)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:65)
    at io.micrometer.core.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send(HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:112)
    at io.micrometer.core.ipc.http.HttpSender$Request$Builder.send(HttpSender.java:306)
    at io.micrometer.elastic.ElasticMeterRegistry.publish(ElasticMeterRegistry.java:129)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry.publishSafelyOrSkipIfInProgress(PushMeterRegistry.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.lockedRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:49)
    ... 11 more


The java.io.IOException: Premature EOF error suggests that the HTTP connection to Elasticsearch was terminated unexpectedly during the response body reading process.
Even if there is no information about incompatibility of elastic and spring, it is better to use the latest version of micrometer-elastic-registry and spring-boot.
However, this problem can appear when elastic is overloaded(check it's logs,increase timeouts and reduce batch size) or micrometer is timed out.
You can also enable additional logging to understand better why connection fails.

How do I enable additional logging?

I was talking about logging for Micrometer and HTTP connections: logging.level.io.micrometer.elastic=DEBUG and logging.level.io.micrometer.core.ipc.http=DEBUG
